# Typescript: import and access JSON with arbitrary keys

Tags: json, typescript, import

I'm trying to import a JSON file with arbitrary keys (e. g. device names) but can't figure out how to access the imported data with variable (unknown) keys at runtime in TypeScript.

**Example JSON file "test.json":**

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": "1"
    }
}
```

**Example TS code:**

```
import t from "./test.json";

let k = "a"          // <- variable key

console.log(t["a"]); // <- ok
console.log(t[k]);   // <- error
```

**The TypeScript error:**
*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: { b: string; }; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ a: { b: string; }; }'.*

I've already read about TypeScript Records and Index Signatures, but how would I import or "cast" the imported JSON data so that it can be accessed using variable keys? The data will (must) be verified at runtime.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4bABN) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: this also works for me and I like the "merge in an index signature" approach. Thank you very much!

Comment: Given that you already accepted a different answer I'm not inclined to write up mine. Take care!

Comment: @jcalz: I hope you're not annoyed that I (impetuously) accepted another answer. If so, sorry for that! Anyway I "distilled" my solution of all the answers/comments posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=29&pln=1&pc=1#code/ATDGHsDsGcBdgFbSsAvMA3sARAQ2wFyY4BGhOAjNsAL4A0Oo5G2AJudlTbQNzAD0-YAB4AtKODQAlgFsArgBtcsAKbBZAB3AAnWACg9IWAE8NagKoxcAMzXosAbQ25tKyLADSK40TjapkADmALpEGA6gABZSCqxePpKw-kGhwLiQxtzcPIYCQgDW3sCQ4PCwGsYqrLkKKvD5aDj4BiAQMGVEltA2dojIkDmtUMi1AHQK4IEAFLAOeNjBAJR8uW0jKuOTMw75S3wggiIS4A0kcvAQiqzA1rgxwCjacu6yKi15kj1pGhra4FG5ExmYAAZS%20qAASioINpWMIAOS4eEAH2A8NA8IY4UKCT8ARCviS%20JoAD5cocgVVgDianVPgA3FTxIg48DWUHgprUEA83mHMTAekuKS4Ei1aneXKrYbwbq2Ihg2wgdBIKCDMDDcBjCbTOUqByI%20FLaUwLUbHVTPUObqM%20J7PRAA)

```
  const json = { "a": { "b": "1" }, "c": {"d": "1"} }; // <-- simulate import

  type Unsafe = { [parentKey: string]: {[childKey: string]: any} } ;
  // key not tpyed
  let k = "a"

  const t: Unsafe = json;
  console.log(t["a"]); 
  console.log(t[k]);   // <- ok but could fail on runtime

  // safe approch
  type Safe =Record<'a'| 'c', {[key: string]: string}>
  // typed key
  let saveKey: keyof Safe = "a"          // <- variable key
  
  const safe: Safe  = json;
  console.log(safe['a'])
  console.log(safe[saveKey])
```

Comment: Could you [edit] this so that it doesn't look like you copied and pasted from my playground link in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76157697/typescript-import-and-access-json-with-arbitrary-keys/76158087#comment134306492_76157697) above?  I don't want it to appear like there's an issue with attribution or plagiarism.

Comment: Sure sorry for that @jcalz

Comment: @heaxyh: That worked for me. Thank you very much! I use the "unsafe" approach because the keys are not known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be working

```
const t = {
    "a": {
        "b": "1"
    }
}
type JsonKeys = keyof typeof t;
let k: JsonKeys = "a"; // <- variable key

console.log(t["a"]); // <- ok
console.log(t[k]);   // <- ok
```

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box because the original JSON structure is more complex (deeper) and than the "keyof typeof" doesn't work. Merging in the index signature works better for me. Anyway, thank you very much for your contribution!